# Connected components of a codimension one fiber for a finite morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a finite surjective morphism from a $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial variety to a smooth variety. Let $D_Y$ be a prime divisor on $X$ and let $\bigcup D_i$ be the inverse image of $D_Y$. Do we know anything about the number of connected components of $\bigcup D_i$?
Does the number equal to the number of $D_i$'s? (i.e. $D_i$'s do not intersect with each other.)
Thanks!

Comment: It is bounded by the degree of the morphism.

Comment: But this is not sufficient...  I expect this to be the number of $D_i$ or at least related to that...

Comment: No, the number of connected components does not equal the number of irreducible components. For example take $X \rightarrow \mathbf P^2$ a double cover branched over a smooth quartic curve $C$. For a line $L \subset \mathbf P^2$ that is bitangent to $C$ the inverse image of $L$ is a union of 2 intersecting copies of $\mathbf P^1$.

Comment: Yes, this is a good example.

Comment: If $f$ is a morphism of curves, there is no better bound than the degree of the morphism.